# databricks on AWS are not printing the value when run as a job

Tags: databricks, aws-databricks

When I tried to run code as job in databricks with multiple `print` command ,job running
successful without executing `print` commands and getting the below error.

```
Failed to fetch the result.Retry
```

[image]